# Turning a generic string array into a union of string literals

Tags: typescript, generics, variadic

I found that when I use a generic variadic, I can successfully coerce a function's input of strings into a Union of the literal values passed

```js
declare function variadicGenericArray<Items extends string[]>(...items: Items): {[value in Items[number]: value}
const test = variadicGenericArray("One", "Two");
type testType = typeof Test; // {"One": "One", "Two": "Two"}
```

However when I try to extract these types using a normal array as the argument, then I don't get a union of literals.

```js
declare function nonVariadicGenericArray<Items extends string[]>(items: Items): {[value in Items[number]: value}
const test = nonVariadicGenericArray(["One", "Two"]);
type testType = typeof Test; // {[x: string]: string}
```

What can I do to ensure that `testType` has the type `{"One": "One", "Two": "Two"}` and still have the function take in an array rather than variadic arguments?

An important note. I'm trying to write a function definition here, and the function is supposed to be **generic**, so I can't just declare `type Values = "One" | "Two"` or `type Values = ["One", "Two"] as const` and use those, since then the function would no longer be **generic**

Answer (score 1):

Played around a little and it looks like I can do this

```js
declare function nonVariadicGenericArray<Items extends readonly string[]>(items: Items): {[value in Items[number]: value}
const test = nonVariadicGenericArray(["One", "Two"] as const);
type testType = typeof Test; // {"One": "One", "Two": "Two"}
```

Now I'll need to figure out which API is the better developer UX, but at least I have an answer now.